# How to fix "Argument of type ... is not assignable to parameter of type ..." error?

Tags: typescript

Given

```
abstract class A {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize()
  }

  initialize<T extends {
    [t in keyof this]?: boolean
  }>(todos?: T) {
    // Do something
  }
}

class B extends A {
  initialize() {
    super.initialize({ // <-- it will throw error starting on this open bracket
        test: false
    })
  }

  test() {
    return 'test'
  }
}
```

Why is it the code above throwing error stating that
`{ test: false }` is not assignable to `{[t in keyof this]?: boolean}`? While it clearly is.

'test' is one of the keys of B, right? and `keyof this` will refer to key of B, right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck i want to extend the functionality of the methods specified on the parameter, e.g: adding an autobind or debouncer.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.initialize()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20initialize%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20this%3E(todos%3F%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20K%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20initialize()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super.initialize(%7B%20%22abc%22%3A%20%22test%22%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20test%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D) ?

Comment: What i love about the sample i've given is the Intellisense is working, but it just throws error. While your suggested answer, although can be used have no Intellisense working. @PatrickHollweck

Comment: This is actually a limitation of typescript, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26610) on their repo some time ago... Maybe there is an alternative solution though. So just so I got this down - You want to pass an object to the `super.initialize` call where the keys are keys of `B` and the values are booleans - The thing is typescript know that keys are correct, but it does not yet provide intellisense for it...

Comment: Subscribed to your bug report. Thank you Patrick.

Comment: I almost had a workaround, but the compiler really wants the `this` context of `super.initialize()` in `B` to be `A`.  That kind of makes sense, but it stops what I was trying to do.

Comment: I actually don't believe this is has to do with abstracts but rather that you are refering to this inside the generic which I believe is ment to facilitate passing this into functions but does as far as I can tell not support keyin as it is not a real reference to the current class type but more a match for the this keyword. I might be wrong but you will still get the error with:
```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize({initialize: false})
  }

  initialize<T extends {
    [t in keyof this]?: boolean
  }>(todos?: T) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Proper Abstract Class Definition

First, you are "cheating".

```
abstract class A {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize()
    //   ~~~~~~~~~~ this `initialize` is from subclass
  }

  // different from this one here
  initialize<T extends {
    [t in keyof this]?: boolean
  }>(todos?: T) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

You just trick TS to think you're calling the same `initialize` method, by give them the same name and compatible function signature (the optional `todos` param).

What you're trying to do should really be written as:

```
abstract class A {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize()
  }

  // fix 1: delcare abstract method
  abstract initialize(): void

  // fix 2: rename, mark as protected
  protected _initialize<T extends {
    [t in keyof this]?: boolean
  // fix 3: todos probably isn't optional
  }>(todos: T) {
    // Do something
  }
}

class B extends A {
  initialize() {
    super._initialize({
        test: false
    })
  }

  test() {
    return 'test'
  }
}
```

---

#### Connection between Subclass and Base Class

**It's one way**. Subclasses know about base class, but base class **is not** obligated to know about all subclasses that extend itself. Because each subclass can implement something different, how is base class suppose to know all these info?

That's the whole point of the abstract class thing. You declare abstract method or property on base class, that's effectively a contract established by base class. Whichever subclass wants to extend me? Sign the contract first! Comply with my terms!

Back to your case, why is `_initialize` in `A` supposed to know any thing about `B`? There could be `C` or `D` extending `A` too. It's just not possible to **infer** the `keyof` subclasses merely from `this`.

So you need to tell `super._initialize` about what subclass is `this` when calling. It's a requirement, not a limit of TS.

```
abstract class A {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize()
  }

  abstract initialize(): void

  // pass subclass type as generic param B
  protected _initialize<B>(todos: {
    [t in keyof B]: boolean
  }) {
    // Do something
  }
}

class B extends A {
  initialize() {
    super._initialize<B>({
      test: true,  // <-- this is correct now
      foobar: true // <-- this triggers error report
    })
  }

  test() {
    return 'test'
  }
}
```

---

You can do a lot of hacky stuff in JS, but don't confuse JS with TS. TS is mostly about best practice, and you hit all sort of quirk and error when you break them. Your case is not a limitation of TS, that's TS trying to persuade you back to the right track.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your time explaining these things to me. I know i am cheating here.. hehe.. but it just a 'curious' cheating, since the Intellisense able to tell me the correct keys to put on the initialize function, but it throws error although i put the correct keys. There must be an incoherence between Intellisense and TS, right?

Nevertheless, i see your point. I am very grateful for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@JGoodgive How then i could have a real reference to current class? As i need it to point current class for later use in class' descendants. I can do this by:

```
abstract class A<Model> {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize()
  }

  initialize<T extends {
    [t in keyof Model]?: boolean
  }>(todos?: T) {
    // Do something
  }
}

class B extends A<B> {
  initialize() {
    super.initialize({
      test: true,
      initialize: false,
    })
  }

  test() {
    return 'test'
  }
}
```

But it seems silly to pass in B into B, don't you think?

Comment: I don't think that is silly this is a design pattern. It even has a name https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Very interesting. I'm sorry for calling it silly. What I thought was, why should it be referenced this way instead of a more direct approach of `this`, since `this` should be available right after an object creation. It is so direct, that referencing it the other way seems silly for me. But yeah, I should learn more. Thanks for the info ya.